# Fixing mixed date formats in data frame?

Tags: r

One of my columns in my data frame looks like so:

```
> head(df$col2,n = 50)
 [1] "NA, 2015"           "November 13, 2014"  "September 27, 2014" "October 8, 2014"    "December 16, 2013" 
 [6] "February 8, 2015"   "November 2, 2014"   "November 30, 2014"  "February 18, 2015"  "August 22, 2014"   
[11] "October 26, 2014"   "January 3, 2014"    "May 5, 2015"        "February 3, 2014"   "October 15, 2014"  
[16] "September 12, 2014" "April 2, 2014"      "April 23, 2015"     "November 4, 2014"   "January 16, 2014"  
[21] "September 28, 2014" "January 14, 2014"   "February 13, 2014"  "January 17, 2014"   "January 4, 2014"   
[26] "February 1, 2015"   "January 14, 2014"   "April 18, 2014"     "October 14, 2014"   "August 20, 2014"   
[31] "January 20, 2014"   "April 11, 2015"     "July 5, 2014"       "November 29, 2013"  "March 22, 2014"    
[36] "December 29, 2014"  "February 18, 2015"  "January 13, 2014"   "January 5, 2015"    "April 19, 2014"    
[41] "November 28, 2014"  "13 August, 2014"    "14 December, 2014"  "10 January, 2014"   "3 February, 2014"  
[46] "17 March, 2014"     "3 July, 2014"       "17 October, 2014"   "28 January, 2014"   "10 October, 2014"
```

As you can see, aside from the first row (which I know to be NA, that's no problem) there's two different date formats between m-d-y and d-m-y. Is there a recommended way to standardize all the dates to m-d-y?

They're all listed as character format in my column of this data frame. I've tried

`> datestest <- as.Date(df$col2)`,

but I get

`Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

as a result.

Comment: Are those all the combinations or are there potentially others?

Comment: I posted a solution that should to the trick. with a `dput` of your data it could be easier to help you. Anyway in my solution instead of `x` you have to use `df$col2` I guess.

Comment: @Elin: just those two

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `parse_date_time` function in `lubridate` allows you to parse vectors with heterogeneous formats using the "orders" argument:

```
require(lubridate)
x <- c("November 2, 2014", "13 August, 2014")

parse_date_time(x, orders = c("mdy", "dmy"))
[1] "2014-11-02 UTC" "2014-08-13 UTC"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- c("November 2, 2014", "13 August, 2014" )
```

It consists of selecting with `grep` the different ways dates are displayed (say, first the ones starting with a number and then use the `-` to select the other ones) and then use the different appropriate function of `lubridate`.

```
 ind <- grep("^\\d", x)
 dmy(x[ind])
[1] "2014-08-13 UTC"

 mdy(x[-ind])
[1] "2014-11-02 UTC"
```

Answer (score 2):

I seem to recall there's a cleaner way to accomplish this with `lubridate`, but I can't recall what it is.  In the past, I've identified the date formats with something like

```
date_type <- ifelse(grepl(df$col2, "\\w{3,9} \\d{1,2}, \\d{4}"), "mdy",
                    ifelse(grepl(df$cols, "\\d{1,2} \\w{3,9}, \\d{4}"), "dmy",
                           NA))
```

From there, you can run another `ifelse` to convert the dates

```
date <- ifelse(date_type == "mdy", 
               as.Date(df$col2, format = "%B %d, %Y"),
               as.Date(df$col2, format = "%d %B, %Y"))
```

That will probably return a number, but you can convert it with `as.Date(date, origin = "1970-01-01")`